# How can I make part of a mesh transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to make some % of my mesh transparent?

For example, imagine I have a mesh that is a house.  At first the mesh is transparent. As a person clicks on the house, it becomes opaque along the Y-axis so it looks like it's being built up.

Any ideas how to approach this problem?

Comment: Mesh is just mesh, you can not see it one way or another.  You mean you want the ***texture*** to be transparent in certain areas. This is difficult.  Google to find 100s of pages discussing this.  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/projecting-a-hole.35808/ If you're not sure what to google try "unity3d make a hole transparent"

Comment: Thanks Joe, knowing what terms to search is often half the battle with this kind of problem.  Knowning to search for "unit3d make a hole transparent" and the other link is useful.  If there are other terms or things that might guide the research, please share :)

Comment: Yeah $30 for a transparency library sounds appealing.  I've done a lot of coding & 3D modeling, but new to Unity so no idea how to approach / judge things yet.  That's interesting that libraries are sold in this world

Answer (score 1):

> "a house. At first the mesh is transparent. As a person clicks on the house, it becomes opaque along the Y-axis so it looks like it's being built up"

Literally in answer to your question, in general:

- I would approach this by making a shader which was sensitive to the global Y value of the point in question. It would use that value, over time, to decide on alpha at a given point.

alternately

- Imagine a second texture of the house, call it GUIDE, which is: imagine a monochrome house: at the ground it is black and it slowly becomes pure white at the tops.  Additionally you could color it any way you want, for example, the window frames and quoining could be black and so on.  Now, the shader would use the GUIDE texture as a key, to know at what time, that area, should become transparent.

That would actually look quite incredible and offer amazing control. You could fade in different parts in whatever order you wish.

It would be beyond the scope of an answer here to actually engineer this. But I believe the key here is, unfortunately for what you describe that is really all done in the shader, I'd say.

- Note that if you just want "a clean hole", look in to approaches using a depth mask shader And indeed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3RKGAj9Uzk
- for 2D consider this, http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/449034/see-through-hole-via-shaders-on-a-2d-plane.html
- in other cases you may literally want to cut a sharp hole in the *mesh* which is a "whole" different technology.  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72978/shader-that-cuts-hole-through-all-geometry
- if you want this effect http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/622089/how-can-i-render-a-semi-transparent-texture-with-a.html (see mario image) that's totally different again - it's nothing more than a gray image with a hole!